# Python like standalone vs. library use checking for PHP

Tags: php

I know Python has name="__main__" check to test if the script is called as a standalone unit of execution or is included in another file to use as a library. Does PHP have a similar test?  One way to do this would be:

```
define('ASLIBRARY', true);
require('foobar.php');
```

And in foobar.php

```
$aslibrary = defined('ASLIBRARY');
if (!aslibrary) {
    ....
}
```

If PHP provides something of the sort, this would obviously be redundant.

Comment: I guess you could do elaborate checks with `$argv[0]` against `__FILE__` and `getcwd`, but it seems to me to be a bad idea to have a file which behaves differently based on how it was called to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
if( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] == __FILE__)
```

`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` refers to the script that is currently executing - if we're in an included file, this still references the initial script, the one doing the including.

`__FILE__`, on the other hand, is a magic constant which will always be the current file, whether included or run directly.

If they're the same, then we're in the directly-called script.

Otherwise... well, you get the idea :)

Comment: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is relative to the document root. Try `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` instead. However, neither of these will work if the script is called from command-line.

Comment: @geomagas Whoops, you're right about the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` thing. Edited. On the other hand, I use `$_SERVER` vars from the command line all the time - while they're not all there for obvious reasons (`REMOTE_ADDR`, for instance) many of them are.

Comment: You may be right. I must rush now, so I leave the confirmation part to someone else. Upvoted anyway! :)

Comment: @geomagas- Verified. $_SERVER is defined for PHP_SELF and SCRIPT_FILENAME at least even when called through the cmd line! Thanks! :)

Comment: Just be aware that if you want to make this a function, say `isParentScript()`, you must pass `__FILE__` as a parameter, otherwise it will be whatever file the function is defined in :p